# How to get items from array element json c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, listbox

### How do i get items from array element json c# ?

---

I want to get multiple artist names from my call, and put them in a listbox.

I can get the first artist like this etc.:

```
    string url = @"http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.search?apikey=key&q_artist=LMFAO&format=json";
    string content = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
    dynamic artistData = JObject.Parse(content); 
    string artistName = artistData.message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_name;
```

But how can i get more of the names and put them in a listbox?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExCKP.png) you can see how the json result looks like

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not create a proper model for your data and deserialize using newtonsoft or a json parser of your choosing. Then all your artists are in an array you can either use a loop or linq to get all the artists names. And I think from their you could figure out how to put it in a list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate it. I figured out i could solve my problem like this:

```
var artistLength = artistData.message.body.artist_list.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < artistLength; i++)
    {
         var artistName = artistData.message.body.artist_list[i].artist.artist_name;

         //printed in the console for testing
         Console.WriteLine(artistName);
         listBox1.Items.Add(artistName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
var artists = artistData.message.body.artist_list.Select(x => x.artist);
foreach (var artist in artists)
{
    var artistName = artist.artist_name;
    listBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(artistName , artistName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the below code snippet to get list of names

```
var artistNames = artistData.message.body.artist_list.Select(var=>var.artist.artist_name).ToList();
```

Then you could bind this list to your listbox either by using listbox.items.add function calls or by making use of ItemsSource property